# How do I put data from sql database into a combobox in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tkinter

[This is the database I want to call from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxKlQ.png)
[This is the empty combobox, When I press down nothing comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDdOs.png)

```
          Label(self.root,
          text="Supplier",
          font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),
          bg="blue",
          fg="white").place(x=0, y=325, height=40) 
          
        Supplier=ttk.Combobox(self.root,
                          postcommand=self.combo,
                          state="readonly",
                          font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15)).place(x=80, y=325, width=420, height=40

def add(self):
    con=sqlite3.connect(database="product.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    try:
        if self.pid.get()=="":messagebox.showerror("Error","Product ID is required",parent=self.root)
        else:
            cur.execute("Select * from product where pid=?",(self.pid.get(),))
            row=cur.fetchone()
            if row!=None:
                messagebox.showerror("Error","This Product ID is already assigned",parent=self.root)
            else:
                cur.execute("Insert into product(pid,name,supplier,price,quantity,description,total)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(
                    self.pid.get(),
                    self.name.get(),
                    self.supplier.get(),
                    self.price.get(),
                    self.quantity.get(),
                    self.description.get(),
                    self.price.get()*self.quantity.get(),
                    ))

                con.commit()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success","Product added successfully",parent=self.root)
                
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(e)}",parent=self.root) ##



def combo(self):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("supplier.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM supplier")
    slist = c.fetchall()
    values = [row[0] for row in slist]
    self.supplier
    con.commit()
    con.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
root=Tk()
obj=productClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to populate the combo box with results found in a database. Then add the results from this into a new database.

Also a different question how can I call to a database and compare the results to the user input. I want to do this to make a login system. I already have the register part but I'm confused on how to call and compare to the database.

Hopefully this question isn't to hard.

**No error now comes up but no results from the database is showing up on the combo box.

Error:
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'configure'

Comment: `ttk.Combobox` has no option command, you may want  *postcommand* or *validatecommand*, or you are looking for the *<<ComboboxSelected>>* event.

Comment: Thank you so much you help get rid of the unknown command error but now it comes up with "c.execute("SELECT name * from supplier") " error. I should probably edit the main post now

Comment: @Thingamabobs How can I put results from the database into the combobox?

Comment: is the result a list of string ?

Comment: Yes the results are all strings. However I only need one of them, the supplier name. I removed the * from "SELECT name * FROM supplier" so I can only select one.

Comment: The postcommand is invoked after the *down arrow* is pressed by the use [see](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Combobox.html)

Comment: I tried using values=self.combo however it gives me a random string number? @Thingamabobs

Comment: You never do something to the combobox in your postcommand. First you need a way to adress your combobox. You may are able to do the changes `self.Supplier=ttk.Combobox(...)` and adress the combobox via self.Supplier in your *combo* function with `self.Supplier.configure(values='my_value')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There should be a comma between `name` and `*` in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `combo` function is fetching data from the database, but doesn't do anything with the data. You must configure the combobox with the data.

Your first step is to make sure you can reference the combobox. Assuming this code is all in the same class you should make the combobox an attribute of the object:

```
self.supplier=ttk.Combobox(self.root, postcommand=self.combo, ...)
```

Next, in your `combo` function you need to set the `values` attribute of the combobox:

```
def combo(self):
    ...
    slist = c.fetchall()
    self.supplier.configure(values=slist)
    ...
```

I don't remember if `fetchall` returns a flat list or a list of tuples when selecting one column. If it's a list of tuples you'll need to flatten it out before assigning it to values, perhaps with something like this:

```
values = [row[0] for row in slist]
self.supplier.configure(values=values)
```

The point is, the function called via the `postcommand` attribute is responsible for updating the values.